# Error response from daemon: Ports are not available

Tags: reportportal

I am getting the following error while trying to install report portal on my local :

Error response from daemon:

> Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 0.0.0.0:0:
> listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: Only one usage of each socket address
> (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Tried to create an image using :

```
docker-compose -p report portal up -d --force-recreate
```

Error message :

Error response from daemon:

> Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 0.0.0.0:0:
> listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: Only one usage of each socket address
> (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Answer (score 1):

The message says your port 8080 is already taken by another process. You could either make sure 8080 is available or re-configure the ReportPortal to use another port by [replacing it here](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L20)